# FIll dots in dataframe with data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with prices of commodities.
However, once in a while some values are just dots.

If they were NAN i would have replaced them with **fillna**.

Or in this case would have replaced symbol '.' with '' (nothing), but the problem is all other values have dots, so that option is not considered.

| Price A | Price B |
| --- | --- |
| 0.92 | 63.86 |
| 0.90 | . |
| 0.92 | 66.36 |
| 0.90 | 65.76 |

Comment: Have you tried `df.replace('.', np.nan)` ? It won't search within a string, it only checks for exact matches. Then you can use fillna().

Comment: it actualy worked, i guess i made a mistake when i tried it first time. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), this will require a full match so your internal dots won't be affected:

```
df.replace('.', '')
```

output:

```
   Price A  Price B
0      0.92   63.86
1      0.90        
2      0.92   66.36
3      0.90   65.76
```

Similarly, `mask`+`eq` enable you to get NaNs:

```
df.mask(df.eq('.'))
```

or similarly: [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

output:

```
   Price A  Price B
0      0.92   63.86
1      0.90     NaN
2      0.92   66.36
3      0.90   65.76
```

*NB. note that in the first 2 options you don't change the type if the numbers are actually strings, in the last one you convert to integer or float*

Comment: Last one did work a bit weirdly when applied to whole set, bcs there was datetime type. But the first 2 did the job, thank you again